# Is there a way to set the fieldtype in lotusscript

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I create a document in the backend with a periodic agent in LotusScript. Now I need to set one field to field type "formula" but I found just a way to set the field type to "author", "reader" or "names" with

```
Set notesItem = New NotesItem(notesDocument, name$, value [, specialType% ])
```

Is there a trick how I can do it?

Comment: You could use `doc.computeWithForm()`.

Comment: The doc for the New method claims that you can only use pre-defined constants for READER, AUTHOR or NAMES for the specialType% argument, but it's an integer argument.  It might just be a question of figuring out the right integer.  You should try 1536.  That's the value that is returned by the NotesItem.Type() property for a formula field. However, that might be the correct value for a compiled formula field, and I presume you are probably wanting to pass in the text of a formula. But you never know... It might work.

Comment: Thank for this hint.. but i does not work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to put your field on a new blank document that you make a copy of when you want to use it via your backend code. Same idea as a template. The field would be left at the type you require. You would just need to change the means of how you compose the document. Since you are possibly looking at using a template doc you might add other fields to your template as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to set the field type to 'Formula'? I don't this type is accessible from LotusScript.

Notes determins the field type automatically, e.g.:

- doc.replaceItemValue( "datefield", now()) will create a DateTime
  field
- doc.replaceItemValue( "numberfield", 23 ) will create a Number
  field

Authors, Readers etc. can be set on the item; NotesItem.IsAuthors = True
or the short form, where you can create the field and se tthe type in one line:

- doc.ReplaceItemValue( "NameField", session.username ).IsNames = true

Comment: i have to use this type because, i try to create mailrules.